# How to extract a string from a line of characters?

Tags: javascript, datetime

`/Date(1396505647431)/`

1. How to extract only `Date(1396505647431)` string from above string using javascript?.
2. How to convert `Date(1396505647431)` string into `DateAndTime` using javascript?
3. How to extract time portion `(like 10:00 AM)` of the above converted date using Javascript.

Comment: What is 1396505647431? Unix timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `string.prototype.match` method:

```
var str = "/Date(1396505647431)/";
```

1. `str.match(/Date\(\d+\)/)[0]` gives `"Date(1396505647431)"`
2. `var time = new Date(+str.match(/\d+/)[0])` gives `Thu Apr 03 2014 11:44:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
3. `time.toLocaleTimeString()` gives `"11:44:07 AM"`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/Z4c4C/)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are looking for timestamp in `/Date(1396505647431)/` string. You can use substring and indexOf functions. **if its follow same format alwayz**

**1.** `var ts = str.substring(str.indexOf('(')+1,str.indexOf(')'));`

```
1396505647431
```

**2.** `var d = Date(ts);`

```
Thu Apr 03 12:07:12 2014
```

**3.**`new Date(ts).toLocaleTimeString();`

```
11:44:07 AM
```

Answer (score -1):

//if it is unix timestap....

var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);

var hours = date.getHours();

var minutes = date.getMinutes();

var seconds = date.getSeconds();

var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

for complete reference ..
[Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)